# Excel/vba latebinding HTML email

Tags: excel, email, late-binding, vba

I have some code written in VBA designed to run in excel which is supposed to send a html email. This worked fine originally but I have tried to late bound me code, an email is still sent however the HTML appears as plain text to the recipient. The code I have is:

```
Dim oAPP As Object
Dim oItem As Object
Const olMailItem As Long = 0
Set oAPP = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set oItem = oAPP.CreateItem(olMailItem)
With oItem
    .To = Worksheets("Emails").Cells(1, 2).Value
    .Subject = "Product set-up request"
    .BodyFormat = 2
    .Body = emailbody
    .send
End With
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `.Body = emailbody` to `.HTMLBody = emailbody`